# Streaming of intranet silverlight page to brightauthor video stream

Tags: http, silverlight, streaming

I have an intranet silverlight page and a digital signage solution called Brightsign. The ds plyers i have are the HD222.

unfortunately they do not support silverlight and re creating the site will take resources that I dont have atm. Quickest solution I found was to have a pc stream the webpage on the network and having the DS player to connect to it. I am using windows media encoder to stream the site.

Unfortunately the feed is not working and Im starting to think that the problem is with the media encoder. Is there a better system or way to get this to work on the brightsign player?

regards and thanks!